# Written Accent with Ag-grid and Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid just with javascript in a razor page to build a grid dinamically. I need to show in the cells the accent mark but I'm still getting the unicode.

If I put the word with accent (e.g., Acción) directly in the row data of the ag-grid. it will show correctly. However, if I define a string variable in the razor, and call it in the same part of the row data, it will be show the accent in the unicode $(acci&-#-2-4-3-;n).

Note: I dont know how to make that the unicode is showed here, so I separated by '-'.

Thanks

```
//Modified for the test.
    var rowDataQualitative = [
        @foreach (var item in Model.evaluacionCualitativaEmpleado)
        {
            string accion= "acción";

            if (item.Equals(lastQualitative))
            {
                @:{Id: "@(item.Id)", NombreIndicador: '@accion', NombreCalificacion: "@(item.CalificacionId)"}
            }else
            {
                @:{Id: "@(item.Id)", NombreIndicador: "@(item.NombreIndicador)", NombreCalificacion: "@(item.CalificacionId)"},
            }
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

After multiples research, I found the method I need to use inside the razor page is **Html.Raw**. The problem was not linked directly with the ag-grid but with the javascript block of code. My apologize.

```
 var rowDataQualitative = [
        @foreach (var item in Model.evaluacionCualitativaEmpleado)
        {
            if (item.Equals(lastQualitative))
            {
                @:{Id: "@(item.Id)", NombreIndicador: "@Html.Raw(item.NombreIndicador)", NombreCalificacion: "@(item.CalificacionId)"}
            }else
            {
                @:{Id: "@(item.Id)", NombreIndicador: "@Html.Raw(item.NombreIndicador)", NombreCalificacion: "@(item.CalificacionId)"},
            }
        }
    ];
```